# Chess.js library. Determine winner and loser

Tags: javascript, chess

Using the chess.js library (see this [link](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js)), I can know if a chess game is finished, by using game_over() function.

But how do I know who won and who lost?

Comment: This would be a great pull request to the library :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`in_checkmate()`

Returns true or false if the side to move has been checkmated.

Combined with `turn()`, it gives you the winner / loser (if it's not a draw).

Comment: I do not understand how this can be combined, because `in_checkmae()` returns the true or a false as well as `game_over()` Help me please!

Comment: If in_checkmate returns true, the player given by turn() is the loser.

Comment: what if game ended with resignation, specifically when the person who made the move resigned

Comment: Resignation is out of the scope of this library. That would be handled by a UI on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: game_over "Returns true if the game has ended via checkmate, stalemate, draw, threefold repetition, or insufficient material". So it may have been a draw too.

I would check:

1. if the game ended in checkmate (there is a function for that), and see who moved last => winner
2. otherwise it is a draw

Keep in mind, though, that a chess game can also be won by the other party resigning, or running out of time on their clock.

Answer (score 1):

You would check

```
chess.in_checkmate();
```

first to see if the other side put this side in check on their last turn. If not and game over then it is a draw.

Comment: how about resign's case?